# Facebook login without registration. Possible?

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to integrate facebook login without any registration into my site? The reason I would like to do this is because I do not want to store any private user data such as password on my database. Is this entirely possible? I've searched the internet for such tutorial but unfortunately most of it requires user to register. Thanks

Comment: No matter what third party signup you use, you'll never be saving any passwords on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use OpenID. You will only need to store some url (its like id). You can find more here: [Facebook Supports OpenID for Automatic Login](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=34189)

But since no one knows if that works, try this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

You can use it. However, you need to store the facebook sessionid of the user in your database.

If you dont want to identify the user next time, you can avoid saving the sessionid also.